# Determine "average min and max" of a list of values

Tags: statistics, average

I've got a large dataset of about 1,000 values which represent the flex of a finger (higher s more flexed). The data is collected within 10 seconds. During that time the finger will be repeatedly flexed and made straight.

I need to find the "average range" meaning that I don't need the global minimum and global maximum but the "average minimum and maximum".

I want to use this "average minimum and maximum" to calculate a normalised finger flex which works independently from the absolute flex value.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you can detect local maxima and minima (look a triples of consecutive values) you are done. If you can't, think of percentile values of the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to give an optimal answer to your question without
definitions of terminology 'normalized finger flex' and 'absolute finger flex'. (These are not terms immediately clear to a statistician, and I am curious about the 'independence' you mention.) What do these two terms mean in terms of finger flexing
and why are they important to you?

Also, it would be helpful to see what the data look like: are
neighboring values in the sequence of 1000 near to each other (for 
instance, suggesting a sinusoidal curve), and about how many
finger flexes are there in a 10-second period.

Lacking this information I have to guess, and the results of
guessing may not be useful to you. It is a little like asking
a physician to diagnose a disorder if you say on the phone, "Sometimes the
twitch in my left eye is very disturbing."

If the data move fairly regularly up and down about 10 times
in 10 seconds, then you might look for several highest local
maxima (about 10) and average, and to look for several lowest local minima
and average them. Do individual flexes result in widely different
max and min values? Do you want to average over all individual flexes, or only get averages for the several most extreme. (By any definition, there would be ways to automate this search pretty
well, so after deciding an a strategy by by looking at a couple of
data streams of 1000, you could have a computer search 
additional such streams.)

Another approach (simpler, more general, possibly less
satisfactory) would be just to average the top 50 values (about) to get
the 'average global maximum' and similarly for the bottom 50
to get the 'average global minimum'. (Of course, "50" is a
mildly educated guess without seeing the data.)

The reason I'd like to know what you mean by 'absolute flex value'
and how you derive that from data, is that your word 'independent'
indicates you want the 'normalized finger flex' to carry
fundamentally different information than the 'absolute flex value'
and I cannot be sure that is true without knowing what
'absolute flex' means.

If this answer sets you on the right track, then please so indicate.
If not, please leave a Comment with more information, and maybe I (or someone else) can do better.

Comment: I've constructed two data gloves. Each finger has a flex sensor in it which ranges from 200 Ohm to 20 kOhm resistance. The resistance is measured and converted with an ADC to a 16 Bit value. This value is what I call `absolute finger flex`. Since every finger is different the range it can flex (and therefore the resistance of the sensors) is different. I want to normalise these values to determine the `relative flex` of every finger. This means for an absolute resistance value I want to determine by how many % of its `average maximum` it is flexed.

Comment: The 10 seconds of samples are meant to be used for calibrating the average min and max values. Within these 10 seconds the user is supposed to keep flexing and relaxing his hand. 
I'm open to ideas for a better calibration method.

Comment: Somewhat clearer now. Try out the idea of averaging the top 50 and the bottom 50 and see how it works. Compare with intuitive view of the initial 1000 (or 10 sec) for several subjects. Do those averages make sense? Maybe adjust the number 50 up or down depending how 'static-y' your data are.

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently improving the gloves firmware and writing two papers. It will take me probably weeks to try out your suggestion but I'll respond how good it works. I'm trying to teach my software recognising hand gestures using neural networks. The ideal situation is that gestures learned with one hand can also be recognised with the other hand.